# View Controller not loading via instantiateViewController function even with correct identifier

Tags: ios, swift

**Goal**: In a separate storyboard that is loaded via a storyboard reference in the main.storyboard, in a pageViewController acting as the initial view controller, I want to initialize an array object of viewControllers via the function .instantiateViewController(identifier:).

**Issue**:  The last viewController I'm trying to instantiate as a constant is not loading. The error - `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load the scene view controller for identifier 'FinalVC''"`

All other viewControllers in this storyboard load fine. This last view controller has a correct custom class linked and a unique storyboard identifier.

**Debugging**: I've created a breakpoint where this view controller is instantiated and noticed in the debugging console all other view controller objects load as "BillyCues.repeatViewController + unique identification number" while this last vc loads as "UIViewController + 0x000000000000000". It's almost as if this vc is not a part of the app bundle or referenced correctly but it's there when I search in the directory.

[Debugging console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVHlN.jpg)

**Things I've tried that did not work**:

- Check to see if another vc has the same identifier
- Clean the build folder
- Check "Use Storyboard ID" in the identity inspector
- `let finalVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "FinalVC") as! FinalViewController`
- Restart Xcode
- Create a brand new view controller with a different storyboard identifier using the same custom class
- Removed all connections from buttons and labels in the last vc
- Made sure all storyboard references in main.storyboard has the correct storyboard linked

**Conclusion**: All my googling has led to other developers encountering the error about NIBs or tableviews not necessarily a view controller. If my vc has a correct custom class and unique identifier the error should not occur. If anyone can offer guidance I'd appreciate it; I'm dumbfounded.

I hope I've asked for help in an appropriate structure but please let me know if more code or screenshots are needed.

**PageViewController Code**

```
    import UIKit
    
    class LauncherViewController: UIPageViewController {
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.setViewControllers([viewControllerList[0]], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }
        
        private var viewControllerList: [UIViewController] = {
            let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.cueCreation
            let firstVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "CueNameVC")
            let secondVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "DueDateVC")
            let thirdVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "IconVC")
            let fourthVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "IconColorVC")
            let fifthVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "RepeatVC")
            let finalVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "FinalVC") as! FinalViewController
            
            
            return [firstVC, secondVC, thirdVC, fourthVC, fifthVC, finalVC]
        }()
        
        var selectedReminderBill: CueObject?
        
        public var currentIndex = 0
        static var cueName: String = ""
        static var cueDate: Date = Date()
        static var cueIcon: Data = Data()
        static var iconColor:String = "14CC7F"
        static var repeatMonthly: Bool = false
       
        // Navigation button functions below to move to the next or previous page
        func pushNext() {
            if currentIndex + 1 < viewControllerList.count {
                self.setViewControllers([self.viewControllerList[self.currentIndex + 1]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
                currentIndex += 1
            }
        }
        
        func pullBack() {
            print(currentIndex)
            if currentIndex - 1 < viewControllerList.count {
                self.setViewControllers([self.viewControllerList[self.currentIndex-1]], direction: .reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
                currentIndex -= 1
            }   
        }
    }
```

**FinalViewController Code**

```
    import UIKit
    import UserNotifications
    import RealmSwift
    
    class FinalViewController: UIViewController {
    
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(true)
            cueName.text = LauncherViewController.cueName
            dueDate.text = CueLogic.convertPaymentDateToString(for: LauncherViewController.cueDate)
            iconBackgroundView.backgroundColor = colorLogic.colorWithHexString(hexString: LauncherViewController.iconColor)
            cueIcon.image = UIImage(data: LauncherViewController.cueIcon)
            repeatsMonthly.text = repeatMonthlyToString
        }
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            cueName.layer.cornerRadius = 15
            cueName.clipsToBounds = true
            
            iconBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
            iconBackgroundView.clipsToBounds = true
            
            dueDate.layer.cornerRadius = 15
            dueDate.clipsToBounds = true
            
            repeatsMonthly.layer.cornerRadius = 15
            repeatsMonthly.clipsToBounds = true
            
            backButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15
            backButton.clipsToBounds = true
            
            saveButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15
            saveButton.clipsToBounds = true
            
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }
    
        let colorLogic = ColorLogic()
        let realm = try! Realm()
        weak var delegate: HomeScreenDelegate?
        var launcher = LauncherViewController()
    
        
        var repeatMonthlyToString: String  {
            get {
                if LauncherViewController.repeatMonthly == true {
                    return "Repeats Monthly: Yes"
                } else {
                    return "Repeats Monthly: No"
                }
            }
        }
        
        @IBOutlet var cueName: UILabel!
        
        @IBOutlet var dueDate: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet var saveButton: UIButton!
        
        @IBOutlet var backButton: UIButton!
        
        @IBOutlet var iconBackgroundView: UIView!
        @IBOutlet var cueIcon: UIImageView!
        
        @IBOutlet var repeatsMonthly: UILabel!
        
        @IBAction func dismissButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
        @IBAction func backButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
            if let pageController = parent as? LauncherViewController {
                pageController.pullBack()
            }
        }
        
        @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
            // Request authorization from the user to allow notifications
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound], completionHandler: {success, error in
                if success {
                    // schedule test
                    
                } else if let error = error {
                    print("error occured \(error)")
                    
                }
            })
            
            let newCue = CueObject()
            let launcherVC = LauncherViewController.self
            
            newCue.name = launcherVC.cueName
            newCue.paymentDate = launcherVC.cueDate
            newCue.icon = launcherVC.cueIcon
            newCue.iconColor = launcherVC.iconColor
            newCue.repeatsMonthly = launcherVC.repeatMonthly
            
            NotificationLogic.scheduleLocalAlertForBill(named: newCue.name, due: newCue.paymentDate, repeatsMonthly: newCue.repeatsMonthly)
            
            saveToDB(for: newCue)
    
            delegate?.loadCuesFromRealm()
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
        func saveToDB(for cue: CueObject) {
            do {
                try realm.write({
                    realm.add(cue)
                })
            } catch {
                print("Error - \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    protocol HomeScreenDelegate: AnyObject {
        func loadCuesFromRealm()
    }
```

**Extension I wrote in another viewController**

```
extension UIStoryboard {
    static let onboarding = UIStoryboard(name: "Onboarding", bundle: nil)
    static let main = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    static let cueCreation = UIStoryboard(name:"CueCreation", bundle: nil)
    
}
```

[Identity Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNmG7.jpg)

[Main Storyboard References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBsJW.jpg)

Comment: Did you try to copy/paste the VC identifier? Might there be an invisible character? Maybe uncheck/check the "Inherit Module from Target".

Comment: I just wrote it in manually and unchecked "Inherit Module from Target" - still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a few things as part of cleanup to start debugging the actual issue. In the storyboard extension, I'd rather use a static function to reference the view controller.

```
extension UIStoryboard { 
    class func createFinalVC() -> FinalViewController? { 
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FinalVC") as? FinalViewController)
    }
}
```

And for implementing it, I'd use in the view controller presenting `FinalViewController`:

```
private func createCreateFinalVC() -> FinalViewController? { 
    return UIStoryboard.createFinalVC()
}
```

And finally pushing it into the view,

```
if let finalVC = createCreateFinalVC() {
    yourNavController?.pushViewController(finalVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I did everything in your post and I was able to get the viewController to appear. I don't have a navigation controller with these viewControllers so instead of `.pushViewController(finalVC, animated:true)` I had to use `self.present(finalVC, animated: true, completion: nil)` Based on your suggestion two things are true 1:Nil is not returned therefore the VC is actually there, 2: The identifier I'm using is working. What is your thought process to doing this for debugging? What should be my next step be if I know the VC is there and is not nil. Does that mean im targeting something incorrectly

Comment: Hey presenting the VC is your target right? Didn't you achieve it?

Comment: Yes. I figured it out. The line of code that was causing the crash was `var launcher = LauncherViewController()` in the FinalViewController. Not sure why.. Thanks for your response though; I learned how to use optionals to debug because of it.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I began a process of elimination and started to comment out all of the code in my FinalVC class. I learned that this line of code `var launcher = LauncherViewController()` was triggering the crash.

Given my limited beginner knowledge I don't know why this would cause a crash; I can only assume that Xcode was trying to initialize two LauncherViewControllers with identical identifier numbers or something along those lines.